# Creating a graphic with four rectangles and four points

Tags: graphics

I created a graphic with four rectangles and four points. The rectangles has a way itself to be created. It is possible to place the rectangles in function of the points

```
pos1 = {0, 1};
pos2 = {-1, 0};
pos3 = {0, -1};
pos4 = {1, 0};
tam1 = 1;
tam2 = 1.5;

g1 = Graphics[{Blue, 
    Rectangle[{pos1[[1]] - tam1/2, pos1[[2]]}, {pos1[[1]] + tam1/2, 
      pos1[[2]] + tam1}]}];

g2 = Graphics[{Green, 
    Rectangle[{pos2[[1]] - tam2, pos2[[2]] - tam2/2}, {pos2[[1]], 
      pos2[[2]] + tam2/2}]}];

g3 = Graphics[{Blue, 
    Rectangle[{pos3[[1]] - tam1/2, 
      pos3[[2]] - tam1}, {pos3[[1]] + tam1/2, pos3[[2]]}]}];

g4 = Graphics[{Green, 
    Rectangle[{pos4[[1]], pos4[[2]] - tam2/2}, {pos4[[1]] + tam2, 
      pos4[[2]] + tam2/2}]}];

points = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pos1], Point[pos2], 
    Point[pos3], Point[pos4]}];

Show[g1, g2, g3, g4, points]
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need modification, but this is the idea.

```
pos1 = {0, 1};
pos2 = {-1, 0};
pos3 = {0, -1};
pos4 = {1, 0};
tam1 = 1;
tam2 = 1.5;
zero = Graphics[{PointSize[0.01], Point[{0, 0}]}];

rect[position_, tam_, color_] := {color, 
   Rectangle[{position[[1]], 
     position[[2]] - tam/2}, {position[[1]] + tam, 
     position[[2]] + tam/2}], Red, PointSize[0.035], Point[position]};

g1 = Graphics[GeometricTransformation[
    rect[pos1, tam1, Blue],
    RotationTransform[Pi/2, pos1]
    ]];
g2 = Graphics[GeometricTransformation[
    rect[pos2, tam2, Green],
    RotationTransform[Pi, pos2]
    ]];
g3 = Graphics[GeometricTransformation[
    rect[pos3, tam1, Blue],
    RotationTransform[3 Pi/2, pos3]
    ]];
g4 = Graphics[GeometricTransformation[
    rect[pos4, tam2, Green],
    RotationTransform[0, pos4]
    ]];

Show[g1, g2, g3, g4, zero]
```

Comment: Yes it would be that the idea. But it is not right your code. It is with some failure.

Comment: Has an error. I am still trying to figure out where.

Comment: I did one modification

Comment: And as to the point, what can be done?

Comment: Re other edits: I wish you wouldn't make so many trivial improvements to old posts every day. It makes the site more difficult to use. Perhaps you could limit yourself to five per day or per 12 hours.

Comment: @MichaelE2 OK. I will limit myself to five per day or 12 hours. I thought that was helping, but I believe that the excessive traffic can disturb.

Comment: @LMC Thank you very much. It does help when limited. But too many means new posts are hard to find.  Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly your question, this should do the trick:

```
g[{pos1_, pos2_, pos3_, pos4_}, color_] := Graphics[{color, Rectangle[{pos1, pos2}, {pos3, pos4}]}]
```

To be used as:

```
g1 = g[{pos1[[1]] - tam1/2, pos1[[2]], pos1[[1]] + tam1/2, pos1[[2]] + tam1}, Blue];
g2 = g[{pos2[[1]] - tam2, pos2[[2]] - tam2/2, pos2[[1]], pos2[[2]] + tam2/2}, Green];
g3 = g[{pos3[[1]] - tam1/2, pos3[[2]] - tam1, pos3[[1]] + tam1/2, pos3[[2]]}, Blue];
g4 = g[{pos4[[1]], pos4[[2]] - tam2/2, pos4[[1]] + tam2, pos4[[2]] + tam2/2}, Green];
```

This does not seem really simpler but you did not give additional details to program an efficient function.

You could also add a red point in the definition of `g`.

Comment: @corey979 Thanks. I do not have privileges to edit with less than 6 words.

Answer (score 3):

> " ... is possible to place the rectangles in function of the points"

The short answer is - no, you cannot use a type `Rectangle` as an input to function `Point`.

Following is a set of `Point` signatures

> Point[p] is a graphics and geometry primitive that represents a point at p.
>   Point[{p1, p2,...}] represents a collection of points.

Comment: I think perhaps the OP's English does not quite accurately represent the thought: My guess is that the OP wants the rectangle to be a function of the coordinates of the points, which is certainly possible.